# how to fetch huge data using id's using EF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to fetch items using entityframework.

I have a collection of 15000 ids, i need amount property of all these items.

What i tried is

```
       var Idlist = results.Select(i => i.Document.Id); //15000 ids
            var amounts = new ConcurrentBag<Decimal>();
            Parallel.ForEach(Idlist, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (item) =>
            {
                var amount = this.AuctionResults.Where(j => j.Id == item).FirstOrDefault();
                if(amount != null && amount.Amount.HasValue)
                {
                    amounts.Add(amount.Amount.Value);
                }
            });
```

but when i execute im getting below exception

```
InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
```

How can i fix this issue? What is the best approach to fetch the items with less time?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a single query is better then 15000 queries...

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

var Idlist = results.Select(o => o.Document.Id); //15000 ids

var amounts = this.AuctionResults.Where(o => Idlist.Contains(o.Id)).ToList()

// and next processing of the amounts

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Martin. Not sure why you are trying to use Parallel.ForEach when you are not really doing any CPU intensive work within the for loop. So something like this should be good:

```
//15000 ids
var Idlist = results.Select(o => o.Document.Id); 

var amounts = this.AuctionResults
                  .Where(o => Idlist.Contains(o.Id) && o.Amount.HasValue)
                  .Select(x => x.Amount.Value)
                  .ToList()
```

Comment: This looks may be better than my answer. hilda_sonica_vish sould to try it and eventual compare performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try materializing your Id list as in

```
var Idlist = results.Select(o => o.Document.Id).ToList();
```

Also, i do not think EF is able to handle parallel operations using the same context even if you do use ToList inside your Parallel.ForEach, cause then you are potentially using the same context instance to run up to 4 different queries at the same time.

You would need to create a new context for each thread.